# Label rotation for 3D plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I am trying to rotate the axis labels in `Matlab(R2015a)`. Here is my attempt:

```
view([49 14])
set(get(gca,'XLabel'),'Rotation',-13);
set(get(gca,'YLabel'),'Rotation',13);
%set(get(gca,'YLabel'),'Rotation',25);
xlabel('Mean Delivery Rate $$a_1$$','Interpreter', 'Latex')
ylabel('Mean Delivery Rate $$a_2$$','Interpreter', 'Latex')
zlabel('Mean Delivery Rate $$a_3$$','Interpreter', 'Latex')
```

which produces:
[image]

This figure is not that good.. How can I make the rotation better ?

Comment: Why is the rotation not good? What do you expect it to look like?

Comment: It seems that the text is wavy

Comment: I just tried your code in a blank 3D plot.  I don't get your "wavy" text, though the angle of the titles is wrong.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/kyfbM.png

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to put `view([49 14])`.. I will edit the question

Comment: most likely there is nothing you can do about this. The text is being rotated and then drawn etter by letter, and there are probably some accuracy issues. If you use 12 istead of 13, looks better.

Comment: You'll need to work out the geometry of the axes box projected on the viewing plane -- i.e., what are the angles of each axis with respect to horizontal when viewed like you want? You've just selected angles of -13 and 13 deg by trial and error.